# Jotul gas fireplace won't turn off

Tags: gas-burner

My Jotul propane fireplace burners will not turn off.  I've disconnected the thermostat from the fireplace unit.  Burners remain lite.  With the thermostat connected, it also remains lite.

Comment: Sure it is the burners or pilot light?  If burners, turn off the gas and have it fix, now.

Comment: Seriously suggest that you get someone qualified to work on gas, otherwise it could easily be your Darwin Award entry.

Comment: @SolarMike  Absolutely agree, I'm really comfortable around electricity but gas, not so much.   Things can go "BOOM" in a hurry, destroying structures and killing people. Love your answer, Maybe add to it and post as an answer.   +

Answer (score 1):

Your gas valve has probably failed. There should be a local cutoff next to the fireplace, depending upon local codes. Just turn it off.

If that's the only propane device in the home, you could turn off the main valve.  But this is a dangerous situation, if  you turned on the main valve again without repairing what I think is a stuck open valve on your fire place, you'd be venting unburned propane into the home.   **Things go BOOM eventually, blowing up your house.**